# How can I make realistic Bokeh shadows?

Tags: shadows, photorealism

I saw a render (attached) with really realistic looking shadows. Any clue how to do this bokeh-style shadow?

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: use point light or a very small light source and have it go through a texture that occludes some of the light. In film is called a cuoloris (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucoloris) 
 Here's a video that shows you how to do this in modo, gbut it cvan be easily done in blender. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaog4aL7AhM to soften the shadows make the source larger.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use geometry:

[image]

In the scene below, the shadow geometry is simply hidden to the camera in render time and has a grey [transparent shader](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/transparent.html#transparent-bsdf) (the color controls the opacity).

[image]
[image]

Or you can use a texture for a similar effect like so:

[image]

Here is simply an image texture with transparent shader.
The light in the scene is a sun lamp.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a great tutorial by Shane Spence Design for Blender and Keyshot that used image sequences of real trees to create this effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYR0wlRmuZI

By using image sequences, you can even animate the shadows created. i assume that the bokeh circles can be achieved by using a larger spotlight.

It's kind of silly to come back here and answer my own question two years later, but I feel like other people would find this helpful. Take care!